# Does not persist entity to db

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

When I try to add data to the database, the hibernate hangs on this point.

```
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
```

Domain class

```
package org.jazzteam.domain.commentary;

import org.jazzteam.domain.id.Id;
import org.jazzteam.domain.event.Event;
import org.jazzteam.domain.user.SimpleUser;
import org.jazzteam.domain.user.User;

import javax.persistence.*;

/**
* @author Yura
* @version 1.0
*/
@Entity
@Table
public class Commentary extends Id {
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private SimpleUser author;
private String description;
/*@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Event event;*/
private int rating;

public Commentary(){

}

public Commentary(SimpleUser author, String description, Event event, int rating){
    this.author = author;
    this.description = description;
    /*this.event = event;*/
    this.rating = rating;
}

public void setAuthor(SimpleUser author) {
    this.author = author;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

/*public void setEvent(Event event) {
    this.event = event;
}*/

public void setRating(int rating) {
    this.rating = rating;
}

public User getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

/*public Event getEvent() {
    return event;
}*/

public int getRating() {
    return rating;
}
}
```

DAO

```
package org.jazzteam.dao.commentary;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.jazzteam.domain.commentary.Commentary;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

/**
* Created by Yura on 14.04.2017.
*/
@Repository
public class CommentaryDaoImpl implements CommentaryDao<Commentary> {
@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public void persist(Commentary entity) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(entity);
}

@Override
public void update(Commentary entiry) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(entiry);
}

@Override
public void delete(Commentary entity) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(entity);
}

@Override
public Commentary findById(int id) {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Commentary.class, id);
}

@Override
public List<Commentary> findAll() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Commentary ").list();
}
}
```

Service class

```
package org.jazzteam.service.commentary;

import org.jazzteam.dao.commentary.CommentaryDao;
import org.jazzteam.domain.commentary.Commentary;
import org.jazzteam.service.Service;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

/**
* Created by Yura on 14.04.2017.
*/

@org.springframework.stereotype.Service
public class CommentaryService implements Service<Commentary> {
@Autowired
CommentaryDao commentaryDao;

@Transactional
public void persist(Commentary entity) {
    commentaryDao.persist(entity);
}

@Transactional
public void update(Commentary entity) {
    commentaryDao.update(entity);
}

@Transactional
public void delete(int id) {
    commentaryDao.delete(commentaryDao.findById(id));
}

@Transactional
public Commentary findById(int id) {
    return (Commentary) commentaryDao.findById(id);
}

@Transactional
public List<Commentary> findAll() {
    return commentaryDao.findAll();
}
}
```

I'm trying to add with this:

```
Commentary commentary = new Commentary(simpleUserService.findById(idAuthor),
            comment,
            eventService.findById(idEvent),
            rate);
commentaryService.persist(commentary);
```

Id generate by class ID:
    package org.jazzteam.domain.id;

```
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

/**
* @author Yura
* @version 1.0
*/
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Id {
@javax.persistence.Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
protected int id;

public Id() {
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getId() {

    return id;
}
}
```

What could be my mistake?

Comment: what is the database you are using in the application. Suppose `Id` class may have the issue. have tried with `@GeneratedValue` or `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`

Comment: I use MySQL, and i tried use @GeneratedValue and @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you're trying to reinvent the wheel.

We might focus closely on your code, but I have a more general suggestion.

You already use Spring and Hibernate. Why not just use it as most people use it in 2017 - with Spring Data JPA.

You can google that and find lots of great tutorials about that topic.

Here is an official Spring introduction: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

a GitHub project with some examples: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples

and a reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/

hope that helps :)

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem by changing:

```
@Override
public void persist(Commentary entity) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(entity);
}
```

to

```
@Override
public void persist(Commentary entity) {
     sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(entity);
}
```

Perhaps it will be useful to someone :)